# package com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer

Tags: jakarta-ee, ssrs-2008, jax-ws

I want to generate war and one of the classes of my project that I use is WSBindingProvider, but when clean and build the following error message:

```
error: package com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer does not exist import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.WSBindingProvider;
```

If someone knows how to solve this or change the content of the classes once the war is generated (comment on the import and the line of code that uses it), I would appreciate your collaboration.

On the other hand I would like to know if it is possible to generate war without parsing the classes generated by jax-ws

Comment: Don't think theres enough information here, how are you cleaning and building?  Command line with Ant or javac using a batch or shell script?  An IDE like eclipse, netbeans?

Comment: I am programming in netbeans, and therefore to generate the .war I use this IDE